# css case sensitivity

Tags: css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are class names in CSS selectors case sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12533926/are-class-names-in-css-selectors-case-sensitive)

In my application am using css classname for styling. But while viewing in the browser the class name applied also css also attached but style was not applied because of case sensitive difference with both in tagclass name and in css classname.
How to resolve this?

Thanks

Comment: CSS isn't case-sensitive outside of URLs.

Comment: Please show a sample of what isn't working.

Comment: The question is good, there are two subquestion: **1) about selectors**. 1.2) [about class names in selectors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12533926/are-class-names-in-css-selectors-case-sensitive); **2) [about property values](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17967371/287948)**.

Answer (score 4):

Whilst CSS is not case sensitive, class names *are* defined as case sensitive in HTML 4.01, so some browsers (particularly [Netscape 6](http://devedge-temp.mozilla.org/viewsource/2001/css-class-id/), apparently) may well implement it as such.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the problem is arising from DocType. Check it out:

http://webdesign.about.com/od/css/f/blcssfaqcase.htm

> Cascading Style Sheets (CSS) is not case sensitve. However, font families, URLs to images, and other direct references with the style sheet may be.
>
> The trick is that if you write a document using an XML declaration and
>   an XHTML doctype, then the CSS class names will be case sensitive for
>   some browsers.

Answer (score 1):

CSS is not case sensistive, but urls and font-families may be.

Answer (score 0):

CSS is not case sensitive. May be you have not included your css in your file or folder path for css file is not correct so it may not be loaded.