# media query, changing left position is not working?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I tired many ways, but I can't get this media query to work.
"#Content" just doesn't change left position when I resize the window !
must be a way to make it run correctly !
Here's the code:
index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
        <title>index</title>
    </head>
    <body>   
        <div id="layout">
            <div id="fixed-sidebar">
            </div>
            <div id="content">  
                content to make error visible ! 
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

style.css

```
* { 
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#layout { 
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}

#fixed-sidebar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 460px;
    background-color: rgb(33, 40, 46);
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 20px;
    color: white;
}

#content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 460px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: lightgrey;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1151px) {
    #fixed-sidebar { width: 460px; }
    #Content {  left: 460px; }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1150px) and (min-width: 700px) {
    #fixed-sidebar { width: 40%; }
    #Content { left: 40%; }
}
```

Here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/X3U2f/1/

What I'm doing wrong ? :/ 
(PS: I tried to put them important but still ignoring left position !) 
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"What I'm doing wrong ? :/ "*

You're using a capital `'C'` for the ID within the `@media` rules, but [class](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#classes) and [ID](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#the-id-attribute) attribute values are [case-sensitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12533926/are-class-names-in-css-selectors-case-sensitive) in HTML, so you'll need to change `#Content` to `#content`:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1151px) {
#fixed-sidebar { width: 460px; }
#content {  left: 460px; }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1150px) and (min-width: 700px) {
#fixed-sidebar { width: 40%; }
#content { left: 40%; }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/X3U2f/

Comment: Thank you very much Adrift ! I'm not used to do this kind of mistakes :p !