# Content Display within Div Area

Tags: css

I'm trying to setup a frame-like area using div, so all the content and picture in the area won't display beyond the area. However, I've tried using different z-index or display but no luck.

http://jsfiddle.net/06xwge5j/

HTML

```
<div id="Parent">
  <div id="Child">
    test content
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#Parent {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
}

#Child {
  position: relative;
  top: 30px;
  left: 30px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: black;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

Comment: Like this http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/ejhmxmLm/?

Comment: *sidenote:* recommend to use lowercase CSS selector names only.

Comment: @Raptor Any particular reason for this? Just curious.

Comment: If you use capital letters, you'll introduce lots of confusion, as HTML are case sensitive: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12533957/188331

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to utilize the [CSS overflow property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow) on the parent element. Add the following line to the `#Parent` rules:

```
overflow: hidden;
```

This will completely hide child elements that are outside the box. Most likely you want to use `auto` instead of `hidden` to show scrollbars only when the content exceeds the box. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/06xwge5j/2/)

### Demo

```css
#Parent {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#Child {
    position: relative;
    top: 30px;
    left: 30px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: black;
}
```

```html
<div id="Parent">
    <div id="Child">
        test content
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/06xwge5j/1/

Take a look

```
overflow: hidden;
```

it hides all content of an element that go beyond its edges.