# IE 11 picks up only some css rules but not others

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I have a `<thead>` that is not displaying its background colour. Yet all other CSS rules work as normal. Here is the code i've written

HTML file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/General.css">`
...
<thead class="tableheader">
```

In my externally referenced CSS file:

```
.tableHeader {
    background-color: #428bca !important; /*blue*/
    color:white;     
}
```

This works fine in all other browsers except ie 11. In the DOM explorer of developer tools, i can see it has picked up other rules from my css file so im not sure why it would skip this one. Any ideas?

EDIT: ok obviously i cant read.. The css rule has a capital H.. but.. my question is still the same. Why the different behaviour? why are some browsers case sensitive and others not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `camelCase` in your css, yet the class name is not `camelCase`. HTML is [case sensitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12533926/are-class-names-in-css-selectors-case-sensitive).

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/v58Lf84L/)

```css
.elementa {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    background: red;
}

.elementA {
    background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="elementa">
</div>
```

Comment: seems that chrome and firefox are case-insensitive. Thanks

Comment: @kapetanios I have to submit my edit, I should have said that while css is generally case *insensitive*, html *is* case sensitive - as stated in the link I provided - glad it helped

Answer (score 1):

You have different `class` name in `css` (`tableHeader`) and html (`tableheader`)

```css
.tableHeader {
    background: #428bca !important; /*blue*/
    color:white;     
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead class="tableHeader">
    <tr>
      <th>
        skdksl
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```