# css difference external style and internal

Tags: css

i've no idea whats the difference between - for me its completely the same
i'm just starting with css...
1st:

```
<div style="float:left">
  <div style="float:left">
    TEST1
  </div>
  <div style="float:left">
    TEST2
  </div>
</div>
```

OUTPUT:

```
TEST1TEST2
```

2nd:

```
<div class="left">
  <div class="left">
    TEST1
  </div>
  <div class="left">
    TEST2
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
DIV.Left {
  float: left;
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
TEST1
TEST2
```

thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12533926/are-class-names-in-css-selectors-case-sensitive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have done mistake. use `left` not `Left`. It is case sensitive. `L` is capital in your css.

```css
DIV.left {
    float:left;
}
```

```html
<div class="left">
      <div class="left">
             TEST1
       </div>
        <div class="left">
              TEST2
        </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS is not being applied use .left{ float:left; }