# z-index not applying correctly

Tags: html, css

I have a landing menu that is made from SVG icons, and now I want to position a div behind these icons, but still inside the menu. Both of these elements have `position:fixed`, and `top` set as a percentage.

So what I want to do is to have the `landingMenu` in the back, then the `landingMenuOrangeLine`, then the `miniNavButton` (so the buttons are in front)

What I wanted to do is set the `z-index` of the elements in question in order to make the buttons appear in front of the div. Now what happens is that I set the `z-index` of `.miniNavButton` to 2, but when I inspect the element in the developer tools it says `z-index:auto`.

Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong? I've setup a [codepen](http://codepen.io/shooshte/pen/ZWRvxq) in case you want to play around with it.

my html:

```
<div class="landingMenu">
    <div id="introductionButton" class="miniNavButton" (click)="changeState('landing')">
        <a>
            <svg class="icon icon-user">
                <use xlink:href="symbol-defs.svg#icon-user"></use>
            </svg>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div id="skillsButton" class="miniNavButton" (click)="changeState('skills')">
        <a>
            <svg class="icon icon-book">
                <use xlink:href="symbol-defs.svg#icon-book"></use>
            </svg>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div id="contactButton" class="miniNavButton" (click)="changeState('contact')">
        <a>
            <svg class="icon icon-envelop">
                <use xlink:href="symbol-defs.svg#icon-envelop"></use>
            </svg>
        </a>
    </div> 
</div>

<div id="landingMenuOrangeLine"></div>
```

my css:

```
.landingMenu {
  top: 1%;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  border-top: 0.1em solid white;
  border-bottom: 0.1em solid white;
  padding: 0.5em;
  background-color: #00B16A;
}

#landingMenuOrangeLine {
  width: 100%;
  height: 0.3em;
  background-color: #FF4C00;
  position: fixed;
  top: 5%;
  z-index: 1;
}

.miniNavButton {
  background-color: #4DC594;
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 0 7.5%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  z-index: 2;
}

.icon-user,
.icon-book,
.icon-envelop,
.icon-eye,
.icon-embed,
.icon-hammer {
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
}

.contactLink {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: add css position: absolute; for those circle ID or class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo error : it's `.landingMenu` not `.landingmenu`

You also can play with the `z-index` property of it to make it appears in front of the orange line or behind.

**EDIT**

To make it have the desired output, you have to put your `.miniNavButton` in the same level of the two other div and put it in relative position. See codepen updated.

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bpKaxY?editors=1100)

Comment: fixed the typo, problem still the same

Answer (score 0):

Simple

```
.landingMenu {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
#landingMenuOrangeLine{z-index:0;}
```

Comment: I need the menu to stay fixed. Also this does not solve the issue

Comment: Ok if you change the landingMenu position value fixed. and set this z-index value higher then  #landingMenuOrangeLine

Comment: the problem is that this will hide the orange line completely. I want the div - landingMenu in the back, then the orange line, then the miniNavButton. Updated question, sorry if it was unclear

Answer (score 0):

I think it's caused by your styles/HTML class names. `.landingmenu` should be `.landingMenu`.

See this [Are class names in CSS selectors case sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12533926/are-class-names-in-css-selectors-case-sensitive)

If you want to have the `.landingMenuOrangeLine` follow the z-index, place it inside the `.landingMenu`.

Comment: fixed the typo, problem still the same

Comment: But the `.miniNavButton`s do have z-index: 2 when inspected. If you want the `.landingMenuOrangeLine` to be behind the buttons, you need to place that line inside the `.landingMenu`.

Comment: putting the .landingMenuOrange line inside the landingMenu div solved it. Please update the answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this below css by replacing..

```
#landingMenuOrangeLine {
  width: 100%;
  height: 0.3em;
  background-color: #FF4C00;
  position : absolute ;
  top : 50px;
  z-index : -1;
}

.miniNavButton {
  background-color: #4DC594;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width : 50px;
  height : 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin : 30px;
}
```

jsFiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/iqbalp95/3bekxmoj/1/