# If CSS selectors are case-insensitive then why styles not overridden?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

From this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12533926/are-class-names-in-css-selectors-case-sensitive), as I understand, css selectors are case-insensitive but HTML attributes (class names) are case sensitive thus IMHO, `.example`should be overridden by `.Example`css selector but that does not happen. `<div class="example">`color is still red and not blue as I thought it would since css selectors are case-insensitive.

```css
.example {
  color: red;
}

.Example {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="example">
  example
</div>
```

Comment: it says `But HTML class names are case-sensitive (see the attribute definition), and that's causing a mismatch in your second example. This has not changed in HTML5.1` so ..

Comment: @golddragon007 he already include that link in the question ..

Comment: From the linked question, the accepted answer says `CSS selectors are generally case-insensitive... But HTML class names are case-sensitive`. As you can see in my code, the html class name `class="example"`is lowercase but css has 2 classes `.example` & `.Example` which should select `div.example"` hence it's color should be blue since `.Example` overrides the color set by `.example`

Comment: As I already stated in my answer, and @treyBake quotes, HTML class names being case-sensitive is why your second rule does not match - because "example" and "Example" are not the same - and therefore there is nothing to override.

Comment: `class` and `id` are case-sensitive. `tags` are not. so `p` or `P` in css will select `<p>` html element. By saying `HTML class names are case-sensitive` it is implied that this is the case when you try to select them in CSS. Not that you are not allowed to use `ExAmPle` as a class name ( it's not recommended though )

Comment: Closing as a dupe as BoltClock's answer in the target explains this.

Answer (score 4):

You are absolutely right! CSS is indeed primarily case-insensitive.

**But** HTML 4.01 defines class and id names to be case-sensitive and this has not changed in HTML5.

> All CSS syntax is case-insensitive within the ASCII range (i.e., [a-z] and [A-Z] are equivalent), except for parts that are not under the control of CSS. For example, the case-sensitivity of values of the HTML attributes "id" and "class", of font names, and of URIs lies outside the scope of this specification.

[Source](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html)

Answer (score 0):

Basically

```
.example {}
```

and

```
.Example {}
```

are two different things now, so it is better to avoid the same names to classes and is a good coding practice not to name two classes as same.