# script not being executed in HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

i am trying to use scripts to get data from my Webapi.

i have tried a few dozen or so different scripts, but nothing ever gets executed.

Script:

```
@section scripts
{
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.cocktail').on('click', function () {
        $.getJSON(url + '/' + $(this).data('id'))
            .done(function (data) {
                $.each(data, function (key, item) {
                    $('<li>', { text: formatItem(item) })
                        .appendTo($('#ingredients'));
                })
            });
    });
});

function formatItem(item) {
    return item.name + item.Volume + item.Dosage;
}
```

}

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">
    <ul class="list-group">
        @foreach (CocktailBasic cocktail in Model)
        {
            <li>
                <b><a href="#" id="cocktail" data-id="@cocktail.Id" class="Cocktail">@cocktail.Name</a></b>
            </li>
        }
    </ul>
</div>
```

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <h2>Ingredients</h2>
    <ul id="ingredients"></ul>
</div>
```

I am completly new to using scripts. everything other than the script works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a couple of potential issues:

- You are using the same ID "cocktail" multiple times - IDs need to
  be unique within the page
- CSS classes are [case sensitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12533926/are-class-names-in-css-selectors-case-sensitive) - Your
  jquery selector is .cocktail but your css class is Cocktail.

Answer (score 1):

There is no element with class `cocktail`, there is one with this ID and a `Cocktail` class.

You'll have to change your selector to `$("#cocktail")` or `$(".Cocktail")`

Answer (score 1):

You have defined your class as `class="Cocktail"` and you have added click handler as `$('.cocktail')`. You should use, `$('.Cocktail')`.