# How to locate the CSS Selector for the nav-menu and the menu button?

Tags: wordpress, mmenu

My website is https://thunderandmiles.com, would somebody be able to help? I've got the Site Nav ID as "Site-Navigation" and the menu button id as "btn-toggle".

Comment: Hi, can you explain your question in more detail? are you trying to be able to apply CSS on those elements? If that's the question and you have id properties in both you should do `#Site-Navitation{...}` and `#btn-toggle{...}`.

Answer (score 0):

The menu button is a class not an id so you'd want `.btn-toggle` for a css selector.

That'll select all elements with that class though. Suggest you add `id="btnToggle"` or the whatever id you like to select that specific element.

Your nav element has the id of `site-navigation` so use a css selector of `#site-navigation` to select it.

Info on case sensitivity here: [Are class names in CSS selectors case sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12533926/are-class-names-in-css-selectors-case-sensitive)