# Why is my CSS file only partially loading when using window.open()

Tags: javascript, html, css, hover, window.open

I am having an issue where I created a new window, imported my CSS, passed over my div and then I import my scripts but the new window is missing part of my CSS rules from what I can tell.

I have it set up so that on hover a tooltip shows up for the button, but in the new window the tooltip CSS rules are not applying although others are.

I have included a [codesandbox.io link](https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-lake-i8csb?file=/tDivStyle.css) where I isolated the issue I am having from the rest of my page. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i've checked the opened window requests and it loaded the css just fine, the problem is that you have a typo in your css class name, the span class  `tooltipText` and your css rule is `.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext`, just change the upper case T.

Have a good day.

Edit: [working fine](http://prntscr.com/wm7195).

Comment: I cannot believe I didn't notice that! Thank you so much! Do you know why it only caused an issue with the new window?

Comment: You're welcome, take a look at the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12533926/are-class-names-in-css-selectors-case-sensitive).