# Why using RegExp to remove class from the class name?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am studying the code at https://youmightnotneedjquery.com/#remove_class:

```
if (el.classList)
  el.classList.remove(className);
else
  el.className = el.className.replace(new RegExp('(^|\\b)' + className.split(' ').join('|') + '(\\b|$)', 'gi'), ' ');
```

I just wonder why it bother to use RegExp to perform the replacement? Why don't use a more simple version, like below:

```
if (el.classList)
  el.classList.remove(className);
else
  el.className = el.className.replace(className, ' ');
```

**Update**
I think the first version has a bug. HTML class name is case sensitive, see [Are class names in CSS selectors case sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12533926/are-class-names-in-css-selectors-case-sensitive), so flag 'i' should not be used in the RegExp.

Comment: What if you want to remove the `"foo"` class name from `class="foosball foobarbaz foo foot"`? Your suggested solution would result in `" sball foobarbaz foo foot"`

Comment: `.replace` only replaces the _first_ instance of the matching string. If you want to remove ALL instances you use a regex. There is a newer method `.replaceAll`, though you'll have to check it's support: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll#browser_compatibility

Comment: @Barmar that's not true, the `className` attribute is just a string, and you can give an element the same class multiple times, e.g. `class='dark footer footer'`. If you only removed the first "footer" in the string, the second one would still be there and the class style would still be applied

Comment: @Jayce444 I know, I deleted my comment after testing it. I assumed it would be canonicalized.

Answer (score 3):

Because you could have a class that contains the specified class as a substring.

Suppose you have an element with `class="abc1 abc"` and you want to remove `abc`. Your code will replace the first `abc`, so it will change to `class="1 abc"` instead of `class="abc1"`.

Comment: Thank you. What is the purpose of className.split(' ').join('|'), this seems useless if I just need: 1. Replace whole word with '(^|\\b)' and '(\\b|$)'. 2 Replace all instances with 'gi' flags.

Comment: `removeClass()` allows you to give multiple classes to remove as a space-separated list. So it's turning `"foo bar"` into the regexp `/(^|\b)foo|bar(\b|$)/gi`

Comment: BTW, that code is buggy. `foo|bar` needs to be grouped.

Comment: And there's no need for `^` and `$`, because `\b` matches at the ends.

Comment: See the other answer, it explains it in greater detail.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like a good approach, either in general or in that particular example.

That regular expression seems to be intended to allow strings that are a space-separated list of class names to be passed, instead of separate strings like you would do with `HTMLElement.classList.remove()`. If you try to pass a string containing a space to `HTMLElement.classList.remove()` it will throw a `DOMException`.

I don't think the regular expression approach you found on that website would work as it's intended to. Let's take a look of a couple of example input strings, and the resulting regular expressions:

```
string: 'class-a'
regex: /(^|\b)class-a(\b|$)/gi
```

This regular expression is pretty clear, it's looking first for either the beginning of the string or a word break, then for the string "class-a", then for either a word break or the end of the string.

Because the line of code contains `className.split(' ')`, it looks like it's intended to handle strings containing space characters. Like this:

```
string: 'class-a class-b'
regex: /(^|\b)class-a|class-b(\b|$)/gi
```

However, because it doesn't wrap the class name section of the regular expression in brackets to create its own group, it ends up being the above. That regular expression is split down the middle by that `|` character, and it looks for two things to match:

1. Either the beginning of the string or a word break, followed by "class-a".
2. "class-b" followed by either a word break or the end of the string.

That means it would match classes it shouldn't for a classList like `class-a2 thisclass-b`.

There's another couple of issues as well. CSS classes are case sensitive, so it doesn't make sense to use a case insensitive regular expression. Also, the regular expression is trying to use `\b` to detect the beginning or end of a CSS class name, but `\b` will also match boundaries between letters and hyphens, so the string `'class-a-1'` would match the regular expression `/(^|\b)class-a(\b|$)/`.

Instead, you'd do better by converting your element's classList string into an array of individual classes using `split(' ')`, then find your class in that array of strings and remove it using something like `Array.prototype.splice`, then rejoin the array back into a classList string and overwrite the old one. Something like this:

```
if (el.classList) {
  el.classList.remove(className);
} else {
  let classes = el.className.split(' ');
  let classIndex = classes.indexOf(className);
  if (classIndex !== -1) {
    classes.splice(classIndex, 1);
  }
  el.className = classes.join(' ');
}
```

Comment: `^` and `$` are redundant, since word boundaries match there.

Comment: Sure, but unlike the other issues with that approach at least those mistakes don't cause any actual issues.

Comment: Very true -- they're just more examples of the author not knowing what they're doing.

Comment: I'll bet he originally wrote `(^|\s)` but someone told him to replace that with `\b`. And in fact, the original code was more correct because of the hyphen issue.