# How to apply border-radius in CSS?

Tags: html, css, border-radius

I'm working on a tutorial-based website design. I've added `border-radius: 40px;` to a CSS class, but the rounded corners aren't showing up.  Here's the relevant CSS and images of the expected vs. actual results:

**Expected:**

[image: tutorial's result with rounded corners]

**My Result:**

[image: my result without rounded corners]

I've already validated my code and checked for typos. Are there other reasons why the `border-radius` might not be working?

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Ubuntu:wght@300;400;500;700&display=swap');
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
}

 :root {
  --blue: #287bff;
  --white: #fff;
  --grey: #f5f5f5;
  --black1: #222;
  --black2: #999;
}

body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.navigation {
  position: fixed;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100%;
  background: var(--blue);
  border-left: 10px solid var(--blue);
  transition: 0.5s;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.navigation ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.navigation ul li {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  list-style: none;
  border-top-left-radius: 30px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 30px;
}

.navigation ul li:hover,
.navigation ul li.hovered {
  background: var(--white);
}

.navigation ul li:nth-child(1) {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.navigation ul li a {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: var(--white);
}

.navigation ul li:hover a,
.navigation ul li.hovered a {
  color: var(--blue);
}

.navigation ul li a .icon {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  min-width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 70px;
  text-align: center;
}

.navigation ul li a .icon ion-icon {
  font-size: 1.75em;
}

.navigation ul li a .title {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: 0 10px;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  text-align: start;
  white-space: nowrap;
}


/*curve outs*/

.navigation ul li:hover a::before,
.navigation ul li.hovered a::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: -50px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: transparent;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 35px 35px 0 10px var(--white);
  pointer-events: none;
}

.navigation ul li:hover a::after,
.navigation ul li.hovered a::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: -50px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: transparent;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 35px -35px 0 10px var(--white);
  pointer-events: none;
}

.main {
  position: absolute;
  width: calc(100% - 300px);
  left: 300px;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: var(--white);
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.topbar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.toggle {
  position: relative;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 2.5em;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.search {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  margin: 0 10px;
}

.search label {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.search label input {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 40px;
  padding: 5px 20px;
  padding-left: 35px;
  font-size: 18px;
  outline: none;
  border: 1px solid var(--black2);
}

.search label ion-icon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 10px;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="navigation">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <span class="icon"><ion-icon name="logo-apple"></ion-icon></span>
          <span class="title">Brand Name</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <span class="icon"><ion-icon name="home-outline"></ion-icon></span>
          <span class="title">Dashboard</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <span class="icon"><ion-icon name="person-outline"></ion-icon></span>
          <span class="title">Customers</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <span class="icon"><ion-icon name="chatbubble-outline"></ion-icon></span>
          <span class="title">Message</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <span class="icon"><ion-icon name="help-outline"></ion-icon></span>
          <span class="title">Help</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <span class="icon"><ion-icon name="settings-outline"></ion-icon></span>
          <span class="title">Setting</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <span class="icon"><ion-icon name="lock-closed-outline"></ion-icon></span>
          <span class="title">Password</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <span class="icon"><ion-icon name="log-out-outline"></ion-icon></span>
          <span class="title">Sign Out</span>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: Check your case-sensitivity.  "Search" vs. "search"

Comment: Thank you, sometimes a silly error can waste time

Comment: Your [mcve] doesn't seem to exhibit the issue in your image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that the code is case sensitive.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Ubuntu:wght@300;400;500;700&display=swap');
*
{
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
}
:root
{
   --blue: #287bff;
   --white: #fff;
   --grey: #f5f5f5;
   --black1: #222;
   --black2: #999;
}
body
{
   min-height: 100vh;
   overflow-x: hidden;
}
.container
{
   position: relative;
   width: 100%;
}
.navigation
{
   position: fixed;
   width: 300px;
   height: 100%;
   background: var(--blue);
   border-left: 10px solid var(--blue);
   transition: 0.5s;
   overflow: hidden;

}
.navigation ul
{
   position:absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   width: 100%;
}
.navigation ul li
{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    list-style: none;
    border-top-left-radius: 30px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 30px;
}
.navigation ul li:hover,
.navigation ul li.hovered
{
    background: var(--white);
}
.navigation ul li:nth-child(1)
{
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    pointer-events: none;
}
.navigation ul li a
{
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: var(--white);
}
.navigation ul li:hover a,
.navigation ul li.hovered a
{
    color: var(--blue);
}
.navigation ul li a .icon
{
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    min-width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    line-height: 70px;
    text-align: center;
}
.navigation ul li a .icon ion-icon
{
    font-size: 1.75em;
}
.navigation ul li a .title
{
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    padding: 0 10px;
    height: 60px;
    line-height: 60px;
    text-align: start;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

/*curve outs*/
.navigation ul li:hover a::before,
.navigation ul li.hovered a::before
{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: -50px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: transparent;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: 35px 35px 0 10px var(--white);
    pointer-events: none;
}
.navigation ul li:hover a::after,
.navigation ul li.hovered a::after
{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: -50px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: transparent;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: 35px -35px 0 10px var(--white);
    pointer-events: none;
}


.main
{
    position: absolute;
    width: calc(100% - 300px);
    left: 300px;
    min-height: 100vh;
    background: var(--white);
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.topbar
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0 10px;
}
.toggle
{
    position: relative;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 2.5em;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.search
{
    position: relative;
    width: 400px;
    margin: 0 10px;
}
.search label
{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
.search label input
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 40px; 
    padding: 5px 20px;
    padding-left: 35px;
    font-size: 18px;
    outline: none;
    border: 1px solid var(--black2);
}
.search label ion-icon
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 10px;
    font-size: 1.2em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Responsive Admin Dashboard | Redesign</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navigation">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <span class="icon"><ion-icon name="logo-apple"></ion-icon></span>
                        <span class="title">Brand Name</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <span class="icon"><ion-icon name="home-outline"></ion-icon></span>
                        <span class="title">Dashboard</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <span class="icon"><ion-icon name="person-outline"></ion-icon></span>
                        <span class="title">Customers</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <span class="icon"><ion-icon name="chatbubble-outline"></ion-icon></span>
                        <span class="title">Message</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <span class="icon"><ion-icon name="help-outline"></ion-icon></span>
                        <span class="title">Help</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <span class="icon"><ion-icon name="settings-outline"></ion-icon></span>
                        <span class="title">Setting</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <span class="icon"><ion-icon name="lock-closed-outline"></ion-icon></span>
                        <span class="title">Password</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <span class="icon"><ion-icon name="log-out-outline"></ion-icon></span>
                        <span class="title">Sign Out</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- mai n-->
        <div class="main">
            <div class="topbar">
                <div class="toggle">
                    <ion-icon name="menu-outline"></ion-icon>
                </div>
                <!-- search -->
                <div class="search">
                    <label>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Search here">
                        <ion-icon name="search-outline"></ion-icon>
                    </label> 
                </div>
                <!-- userImg -->
                <div class="user">
                    <img src="user.jpg" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.5.2/dist/ionicons/ionicons.esm.js"></script>
    <script nomodule src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.5.2/dist/ionicons/ionicons.js"></script>

    <script>
        //ad hovered class in selected list item
        let list = document.querySelectorAll('.navigation li');
        function activeLink(){
            list.forEach((item) =>
            item.classList.remove('hovered'));
            this.classList.add('hovered');
        }
        list.forEach((item) =>
        item.addEventListener('mouseover',activeLink));
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your explanation isn't very specific. Much of HTML and CSS is _not_ case-sensitive.

Comment: Can be confusing, obviously, about what is case-sensitive (or not) between the different elements that are in play with HTML and CSS.  My general advice, these days, is to just assume case-sensitivity, and you'll be safer overall.  This question has some useful answers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12533926/are-class-names-in-css-selectors-case-sensitive

Comment: You are welcome, and it is correct that it is not always case sensitive, however the recommendation is to put exactly the same characters in upper or lower case in both html and css because although in css is not distinguished in html yes, more information about this in: https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2
https://caniuse.com/css-case-insensitive and https://www.w3.org/International/tests/html-css/selectors-case/results-selectors-case

Translated with www.DeepL.com/Translator (free version)