# Angular & Jasmin unit testing "queryAll(By.css" is not working with NG elements

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

So I have this strange problem that I need fixed in order to complete a unit test for a project I'm working on.

My unit test currently looks like this:

```
    it('should display the navbar list', () => {

    component.courses = jsonData.hamburgerMenu[0].menuItems;

    fixture.detectChanges;
  
    const links = el.queryAll(By.css(".NavMenuItem"));
    
    expect(links).toBeTruthy("Could not find links");
    
    console.log(jsonData.hamburgerMenu[0].menuItems)
    
    console.log(links);    

  });
```

with the corresponding HTML looking like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let appMenuItem of courses; let i=index;" class="NavMenuItem">
```

The problem is, when I console.log *links* with an HTML element WITHOUT an "ngIf" or "ngFor" statement, it returns a "[DebugElement]." If I console.log an HTML element WITH an "ngIf" or "ngFor" statement, it gives me a "[ ]." This is problematic because I need to include the following code for my unit test to work:

```
expect(links.length).toBe(12, "Unexpected number of links");
```

but, if my *queryAll(By.css* is returning nothing when used on an HTML component with an "ngFor," then that condition will not work. How do I solve this issue?

For those of you who are wondering, yes, the mock data is there. *jsonData.hamburgerMenu[0].menuItems* contains the following data:

[image]

Comment: you are not calling `fixture.detectChanges()` in your code.

Comment: Also, mixing case in class names is not a great idea. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12533926/are-class-names-in-css-selectors-case-sensitive

Answer (score 0):

Some ideas for debugging:

- Run the test in a browser window and check

  - Are the elements you expect shown in the browser?
  - Do you find the elements with your selector? (-> Open the elements tab in the browser dev tools, press ctrl + f and enter `.NavMenuItem`)
- Does your logic include async code? (In that case, you might need an [async way of testing](https://jasmine.github.io/tutorials/async))

  - Use `fakeAsync` in your test to check if there a still open timers. (The test will fail in that case.)
- What is `appMenuItem`? Is it just a variable name? It sounds like a directive or component.